# vuejs @import not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js

**Unexpected token import.**

While importing **vue-form** in VueJS with Laravel 5.4 project.
Getting stuck to use **vue-form** with **Laravel**.

using this Repository
https://github.com/fergaldoyle/vue-form

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can I see your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please visit the help centre and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am using this form and not able to Setup in localhost.
https://github.com/fergaldoyle/vue-form

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using this line `import VueForm from 'vue-form';`

You'll need webpack + babel (or any other module bundler + ES6 compiler). 
If you're not using a module bundler you can use the `VueForm` global which is created.